# Can I build a CNN for image classification tasks just with OpenCV?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, image-recognition, opencv

I have practiced building CNNs for image classification with TensorFlow, which is a nice library with good documentation and tutorials. However, I found that TensorFlow is too complicated and cumbersome.

Can I build a CNN for image classification tasks just with OpenCV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV does include 2D filter convolution functions for custom [separable](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga910e29ff7d7b105057d1625a4bf6318d) and [non-separable](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) filters. The latter uses DFT for large filters, which may or may not be faster than the conventional method. It also includes (partial?) support for [deep nets](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html) with [various types of layers](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d87/group__dnnLayerList.html). Theoretically, you should be able to stitch everything together into a complete CNN. However, I have not used any of those, and I have no idea about the level of maturity of the implementation.

That said, if you are willing to implement a custom CNN from scratch, you will probably get more control over the implementation using a generic (BLAS / OpenCL / CUDA) matrix library.